# Не могу разобраться как работает вторичный ключ в Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Создал модель Баланс пользователей, в нем вторичный ключ user.

```
class UserBalance(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Баланс пользователя'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Баланс пользователей'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Логин пользователя')
    balance = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Баланс')
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Я не знаю как редактировать и создавать новые записи в этой Модели, т.е как обращаться к полю user ? В интернете посмотрел такой вариант для вывода баланса:

```
UserBalance.objects.get(user__username=request.user.username).balance
```

А как создать новую запись ? Такой вариант не работает:

```
UserBalance.objects.create(user__username=request.user.username, balance=1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UserBalance.objects.create(balance=1000, user=request.user)
```

Для такого рода полей, которые ссылаются на другие модели, надо передавать экземпляр класса той модели, на которую мы ссылаемся. В нашем случае user, который получается из http запроса.

Ещё вариант создания записи:

```
balance = UserBalance(balance = 1000, user=request.user)
balance.save()
```